# Question about applying Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

**Question:**

$\phi_n(x)=\int_{x_0}^xf(t,\phi_n(t))dt$, where $\phi_n(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous and bounded on $[a,b]\times(-\infty,+\infty)$.

1. If $\phi_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $\phi(x)$, prove that $\phi(x)=\int_{x_0}^xf(t,\phi(t))dt$.
2. If $\phi_n(x)$ just converges to $\phi(x)$, **can we draw the same conclusion by applying Dominated Convergence Theorem like this:**

*$|f|\leqslant M,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{x_0}^xf(t,\phi_n(t))dt=\int_{x_0}^x\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(t,\phi_n(t))dt=\int_{x_0}^xf(t,\phi(t))dt$, the first equation by DCT and the second by continuity of $f$.*

**Attempt:**

1. Since $\phi_n$ uniformly converges to $\phi$,then $\phi_n$ is bounded and $\phi$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. So $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]\times[-M,M]$,where $|\phi_n|,|\phi|<M$.

Therefore $f(t,\phi_n(t))$ converges uniformly, so we can exchange the limit and integral.

Is that correct? Thanks for checking!

2. I'm wondering if DCT is correctly used here. Can we use $M(|f|<M)$ as the dominating function?

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: @JackT Question 2 is what i've done,trying to 'prove' it by DCT.And Question 1 i think maybe we can use the uniform continuity of $f(t,\phi_n(t))$ so that we can exchange the limits and integral.

Comment: It looks like you need some sort of fixed point theorem for the first. Are there any restrictions on what you can use?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur nope.Any answer is appreciated:)

Comment: For any $a\leq x\leq b$
$$|\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)|\leq\int^b_a|f(t,\phi_n(t))-f(t,\phi(t))|\,dt$$

Answer (score 1):

DCT does work here(in the sense of Lesbegue integral),for $g(t)=f(t,\phi(t))$ is measurable(as the limit of a continuous function series) and integrable($|g|\leq M$ on $[a,b]\times [-R,R]$,for some $R$ large enough).However,$g(t)$ may not be Riemann integrable since $\phi(t)$ may not be integrable.

Comment: So what if $\phi$ is not Riemann integrable?

Comment: @OliverDíaz so we cannot talk about the Riemann integral of $f(t,\phi(t))$.It is from an ode textbook and the original statement requires $\phi_n(t)$ to be uniformly convergent and is proved by exchanging limits and integrals by uniform convergence,and i was then doubtful about whether DCT could be used here directly.Since the original statement is in the Riemann integrable sense,I think we can use DCT but $\phi_n(t)$ converging uniformly is necessary(or at least $\phi(t)$ is Riemann integrable).

Comment: your assumptions imply that $\phi$ is continuous